# Add line numbers to exceptions in google analytics for Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, exception

I've connected my Swift app with Google Analytics and added `trackUncaughtExceptions` method like that:

```
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true
```

When I get exceptions in GA panel they look like:

```
EXCEPTION DESCRIPTION: NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] ___forwarding___ _CF_forwarding_prep_0 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTarge
```

Is it possible to add line number and file where the exception was generated?